# Repairing a heat gun

Tags: soldering, repair

I've got a heat gun that has stopped working.  Use of a multimeter tells me that there's a single part that is stopping current from flowing through the whole thing.  This part is indicated

```
PATENTED
MICROTEMP™
4468A1
SUUC240C
```

Some research suggests that it is a [fusible link](http://www.belthermal.com/products/parts-and-accessories/fusible-links-micro-devices-4-series-with-cross-references/) which opens (*has opened*, apparently) at 468F (242°C).

How dangerous would it be to cut this part out and join the wires which previously connected to it?  Would using solder to hold them together provide a similar temperature backstop in that the gun would stop working when that area exceeded the melting temperature of solder?  Would it be better to join the devices in a way which did not rely on solder to hold them together?

The part is located between the fan and the heating element, the heating element being at the air exit point of the gun and the fan being at the back/intake.

The wires are thick enough and the design of the gun such that the wires will hold their position and not flap around dangerously inside if the solder is melted.

It's notable that there is no solder used anywhere in the device: clamps and other techniques are used instead.

Comment: Why not crimp a new one in place?

Comment: Mostly just the complication and delay involved in acquiring crimps and a replacement part.  Also, they cost about $10: http://catalog.selcoproducts.com/item/thermal-fuses/one-shot-thermal-cutoffs/swtc-464-3535

Answer (score 4):

How dangerous?  Very. You might not die immediately, but something bad will happen eventually.

Look at it this way, something made the thing overheat and the safety device kicked in.  Now, you want to remove the safety device not not fix the thing that made it activate in the first place.  So now you have something dangerous and no safety device.

Heat guns are cheap.  Throw that one away and buy a new one.  Is your life and/or home worth the $25 for a new one?

Comment: I never said I wasn't going to fix the original problem :)  But I'd like to make sure it still works to some degree first.

Comment: @intuited  It's a judgement call, and therefore there is room for everyone to disagree.  I personally wouldn't bother fixing it.  The cost savings vs. risk vs. time required isn't in favor of fixing it **for me**.  I'm probably qualified to fix it, but I'd choose not to. There are others who would probably fix it, and fix it well.  To each his own.

Comment: So what about using the solder as a heat failsafe?  Solder's melting point is well below the opening point of the fusible link.

Comment: @intuited  You could solder it, but if you can crimp it that would be better-- if only because it stays consistent with how the rest was made.

Comment: I mean using solder as a crude replacement for the fusible link.   Not a particularly sensible long-term solution, but could be useful for testing and careful use..?

Comment: @intuited  At best, the solder will melt at too high of a temperature to be useful.  At worst, it will melt and flow into someplace where it should not flow to.